# Export whole table to CSV using laravel

Tags: php, csv, export, laravel-3, fputcsv

I am new to laravel and having a tough time figuring out a way to export one table to csv.
I have tried the following code in the controller class, but it gives me an error:

```
    public function get_export()
{
    $table = Cpmreport::all();
    $file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        fputcsv($file, $row);
    }
    fclose($file);
    return Redirect::to('consolidated');
}
```

Model Class for Cpmreport:

```
    class Cpmreport extends Eloquent
    {
      public static $table='cpm_report';
    }
```

The error :

```
    Message:

    fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

    Location:

    C:\xampp\htdocs\cpm_report\application\controllers\cpmreports.php on line 195
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Laravel to Download table as CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146719/use-laravel-to-download-table-as-csv) - see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/321521

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fputcsv($file, $table);` should be `fputcsv($file, $row)`, shouldn't it?

And convert the object to an array using Eloquent's `to_array()`method: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#to-array

```
public function get_export()
{
    $table = Cpmreport::all();
    $file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        fputcsv($file, $row->toArray());
    }
    fclose($file);
    return Redirect::to('consolidated');
}
```

Comment: yes, sorry that was a typo, but it is still not working with $row

Comment: Have a look at Eloquent's `to_array()` method. http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#to-array

Answer (score 22):

Easy way

```
Route::get('/csv', function() {
  $table = Cpmreport::all();
  $output='';
  foreach ($table as $row) {
      $output.=  implode(",",$row->toArray());
  }
  $headers = array(
      'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
      'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="ExportFileName.csv"',
  );

  return Response::make(rtrim($output, "\n"), 200, $headers);
});
```

Comment: $output= inside foreach gets the last value

Comment: Note that this requires an eloquent collection query to get the `$table`. A `DB::('tablename')` query will need to be run as an eloquent query and a model created (if it's not been already)

Comment: doesn't create newlines

Comment: you can add "\n" at every end of the line

Comment: Note this doesn't escape any commas, quotes, or the like. Best to use `fputcsv` as demonstrated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27596496/4233593).

Answer (score 3):

Select query of MySQL data.

```
$data = \DB::connection('mysql')->select($select);
```

Call following function:

```
query_to_csv($data, 'data.csv');

function data_to_csv($data, $filename)
    {
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }
```

0.1 Million records takes 1 second to create.

Comment: I've 5000 records but its taking around 3-4 minutes using Laravel 5

Comment: It doesn't take that much time. Might be issue with file permissions? @tiGer

Comment: I'm directly downloading the file, didn't understand about file permissions.

Answer (score -1):

this is better and simple.

```
$file_name = "abc";
$postStudent = Input::all();
$ck = DB::table('loan_tags')->select('LAN')->where('liabilitiesId', $postStudent['id'])->get();
$i = 0;
foreach ($ck as $row) { 

              $apps[$i]['LAN'] = $row->LAN;
            $apps[$i]['Account_number'] =   $postStudent['account_number'];
            $apps[$i]['Bank_Name'] =  $postStudent['bank_name'];
            $i++;
}

ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
Excel::create($file_name, function($excel) use($apps){
        $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($apps){

           $sheet->row(1, array(
                 'LAN', 'Account number' , 'Bank Name'
            ));
            $k = 2;
             foreach ($apps as $deta) {
                 $sheet->row($k, array($deta['LAN'],   $deta['Account_number'], $deta['Bank_Name']
                ));
                $k++;
             }
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
```