# CSV export in laravel 5 controller

Tags: php, csv, laravel, laravel-5

So I have made a little ajax request to my `reviewsController@export`.

Now when I `console.log()` the data in my success method, the ajax response shows the correct data. However my CSV has not downloaded. So I have all the right info and have created the csv essentially.

I think this has possibly to do with setting the headers maybe?

```
public function export()
{
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $reviews = Reviews::getReviewExport($this->hw->healthwatchID)->get();
    $columns = array('ReviewID', 'Provider', 'Title', 'Review', 'Location', 'Created', 'Anonymous', 'Escalate', 'Rating', 'Name');

    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $columns);

    foreach($reviews as $review) {
        fputcsv($file, array($review->reviewID,$review->provider,$review->title,$review->review,$review->location,$review->review_created,$review->anon,$review->escalate,$review->rating,$review->name));
    }
    exit();
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here, or does Laravel have something to cater for this?

Comment: AFAIK this is not working because you are calling this feature using Ajax and ajax may not be supporting download headers. Is there any specific requirement to use ajax? I guess you can directly call that script and set appropriate headers so it should be on same page and CSV will get generate.

Comment: I just prefer using ajax as it doesn't make the page reload. Looks better

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this version out - this should allow you to get a nice output using `Response::stream()`.

```
public function export()
{
    $headers = array(
        "Content-type" => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
    );

    $reviews = Reviews::getReviewExport($this->hw->healthwatchID)->get();
    $columns = array('ReviewID', 'Provider', 'Title', 'Review', 'Location', 'Created', 'Anonymous', 'Escalate', 'Rating', 'Name');

    $callback = function() use ($reviews, $columns)
    {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $columns);

        foreach($reviews as $review) {
            fputcsv($file, array($review->reviewID, $review->provider, $review->title, $review->review, $review->location, $review->review_created, $review->anon, $review->escalate, $review->rating, $review->name));
        }
        fclose($file);
    };
    return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}
```

(Adapted from this SO answer: [Use Laravel to Download table as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146719/use-laravel-to-download-table-as-csv/27596496#27596496))

Try using a regular link with `target="_blank"` rather than using JavaScript/AJAX. Because it's a file download opening in a new tab, the user experience shouldn't be too clunky.

Comment: this gives me the error: FatalErrorException in ReviewsController.php line 90:
syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: Missing semicolon after the closure definition (right before the `return`)! Sorry.  :S

Comment: ok it doesnt error now, but it just does the same thing my code did. Returns the correct format and logs it in the console. but does not force a download

Comment: Can you just use a `target="_blank"` link rather than using JavaScript/AJAX? Because it's a file download opening in a new tab, the user experience shouldn't be clunky.

Comment: got it working now from just linking the to the url instead of ajax lol

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should've just said that from the start!  :P

Comment: aha thanks any way, i will mark you as correct answer anyway as your code does work for the export

Comment: No problem. I'll edit the answer to add the bit about avoiding AJAX!

Comment: Hey, @Nerdwood. I've just edited your answer to add the missing file handler when calling `fclose`. I tried your solution with L5.4 and got an error due to that. After adding that, it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Newer versions of Laravel removed the `Response::stream()` function. Instead, use `response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);`

Comment: For laravel 5.7.*, `return response()->streamDownload($callback, 'prefix-' . date('d-m-Y-H:i:s').'.csv', $headers);` [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses)

Comment: It works locally for me. But on the serve I keep getting this error: "The content cannot be set on a StreamedResponse instance." Any Idea why?

Comment: @DhawalM Perhaps the content is null somehow? In other places that will trigger the error you're getting.

Comment: can someone please tell me what is  `$reviews = Reviews::getReviewExport($this->hw->healthwatchID)->get();` sorry im new to programming.

Comment: @Shrikant I don't know the details (it's not my original code), but this line is getting an array of data (about reviews), which is later being looped through (foreach loop). getReviewExport() is a method belonging to the Reviews class, and it is being passed an ID (to get the reviews for). healthwatchID is a property of the $this->hw object. Not sure if that helps!  :)

Comment: @Nerdwood Thanks for the reply. I got this.

Comment: I am using this is Laravel 5.4 and always getting error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::header().

Comment: Thank you so much this is one of those answers which can run even without packages which saves alot of time for existing old projects. :D

Comment: It returns back "ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE"

Answer (score 18):

### My approach in Laravel 5.7

```
/**
 * @param array $columnNames
 * @param array $rows
 * @param string $fileName
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse
 */
public static function getCsv($columnNames, $rows, $fileName = 'file.csv') {
    $headers = [
        "Content-type" => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=" . $fileName,
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
    ];
    $callback = function() use ($columnNames, $rows ) {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $columnNames);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            fputcsv($file, $row);
        }
        fclose($file);
    };
    return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}

public function someOtherControllerFunction() {
    $rows = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]];//replace this with your own array of arrays
    $columnNames = ['blah', 'yada', 'hmm'];//replace this with your own array of string column headers        
    return self::getCsv($columnNames, $rows);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "replace with your own array of arrays"..

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi `[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]]` is just sample data that wouldn't make sense for you to use in your application. So customize that part for your needs. Same with `['blah', 'yada', 'hmm']`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<?php

public function download()
{
    $headers = [
            'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
        ,   'Content-type'        => 'text/csv'
        ,   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=galleries.csv'
        ,   'Expires'             => '0'
        ,   'Pragma'              => 'public'
    ];

    $list = User::all()->toArray();

    # add headers for each column in the CSV download
    array_unshift($list, array_keys($list[0]));

   $callback = function() use ($list) 
    {
        $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        foreach ($list as $row) { 
            fputcsv($FH, $row);
        }
        fclose($FH);
    };

    return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers); //use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

}
```

**Note: Works only if you don't load relationships, otherwise it will give exception**

Comment: *Array to string conversion* at `fputcsv($FH, $row);`

Comment: hello @HoàngĐăng , it worked in my project, maybe was a previous PHP/Laravel version, if you find the issue you could correct the answer thank you

Comment: Hello @HoàngĐăng, How to move the file into a specific folder to Get a Downloadable Link just send me a string but I need a File.

Comment: quick, clean and simple code!!!

Answer (score 4):

This may not answer your question directly, but I'm using a package called '[thephpleague/csv](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv)' for this purpose...

To use this package:

1. composer require league/csv
2. Put the following 'use' statements in your controller:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
   use League\Csv\Writer;
   use Schema;
   use SplTempFileObject;
   ```

   and any model classes you plan on using.
3. Abstract CSV creating code to a function (in your controller), e.g:

   ```
   /**
    * A function to generate a CSV for a given model collection.
    *
    * @param Collection $modelCollection
    * @param $tableName
    */
   private function createCsv(Collection $modelCollection, $tableName){

       $csv = Writer::createFromFileObject(new SplTempFileObject());

       // This creates header columns in the CSV file - probably not needed in some cases.
       $csv->insertOne(Schema::getColumnListing($tableName));

       foreach ($modelCollection as $data){
           $csv->insertOne($data->toArray());
       }

       $csv->output($tableName . '.csv');

   }
   ```
4. In your controller, create get function to retrieve/download CSV (replace 'MainMeta' with your own model class):

   ```
   public function getMainMetaData(){

       $mainMeta = MainMeta::all();

       // Note: $mainMeta is a Collection object 
       //(returning a 'collection' of data from using 'all()' function), 
       //so can be passed in below.
       $this->createCsv($mainMeta, 'main_meta');
   }
   ```

   When you create a route to call this function, it will download a CSV file in your browser, of your chosen Model collection/data.
5. Create a route in App\Http\routes.php like the following:

   ```
   Route::get(
       '/data/download/main_meta',
       [
           'as' => 'data/download/main_meta',
           'uses' => 'YourController@getMainMetaData'
       ]
   );
   ```
6. (Optional) In a blade view file (e.g. data.blade.php), include a link or button so you can easily access the download url/route:

   ```
   <p><a href="{{ URL::route('data/download/main_meta') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-left">Download Main Meta Data</a></p>
   ```

   When you click on the link, the CSV file will be downloaded in your browser. In an application I have coded, you will stay on the page you click this link.

Of course, this will differ depending on your own application. There is so much more you can do with this package (full documentation is at http://csv.thephpleague.com/). The project I am using this in is at https://github.com/rattfieldnz/bitcoin-faucet-rotator - I have just started coding on it again after a few months away, so still have a bit of refactoring/testing/tidying up to do :).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little package [LaravelCsvGenerator](https://github.com/Eugene-Melbourne/laravel-csv-generator)

and placed it on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/eugene-melbourne/laravel-csv-generator)

Installation

```
$ composer require  eugene-melbourne/laravel-csv-generator
```

example of use in your controller

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function getCsv(): \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse
    {
        $data    = [
                [1, 2.1],
                [3, "hi, there"],
            ];
        $headers = ['one', 'two'];
        $data = array_merge([$headers], $data);

        return (new \LaravelCsvGenerator\LaravelCsvGenerator())
                ->setData($data)
                ->renderStream();
    }
```

Please, do not hesitate to comment your ideas below this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the file on the server (either temporary or on a disk) and send the url to the file to the frontend. Then just trigger a normal download via javascript.

```html
public function export(Request $request) 
{


You have to store the file on the server (either temporary or on a disk) and send the url to the file to the frontend. Then just trigger a normal download via javascript.

Thank you that's what i just did right now 

public function export(Request $request) 
{
    $filename = Carbon::now()->format('Ymdhms').'-Products.xlsx';
    Excel::store(new ProductsExport, $filename);
    $fullPath = Storage::disk('local')->path($filename);

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $fullPath,
        'message' => 'Products are successfully exported.'
    ], 200);
}



$filename = Carbon::now()->format('Ymdhms').'-Products.xlsx';
Excel::store(new ProductsExport, $filename);
$fullPath = Storage::disk('local')->path($filename);

return response()->json([
    'data' => $fullPath,
    'message' => 'Products are successfully exported.'
], 200);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simples way

```
        $headers = [
        'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
        ,   'Content-type'        => 'text/csv'
        ,   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=leads.csv'
        ,   'Expires'             => '0'
        ,   'Pragma'              => 'public'
    ];
    $leads = []
    return response(view('exports.leads.csv', [ 'leads' => $leads ]))
        ->withHeaders($headers);
```