# Laravel 5.2 stream download

Tags: php, download, laravel-5

I'm getting a bit muddled with a CSV download. I'm very happy to save it to a file and supply a link to the user, but this seems like the wrong way to go judging from things [like](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/the-best-way-to-create-and-export-a-csv-from-a-model?page=1#reply-18240) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146719/use-laravel-to-download-table-as-csv#answer-27596496).

Going from this answer [Use Laravel to Download table as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146719/use-laravel-to-download-table-as-csv#answer-27596496) I think I've found that the `stream()` method no longer exists.

```
public function download()
{
    $headers = [
            'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
        ,   'Content-type'        => 'text/csv'
        ,   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=galleries.csv'
        ,   'Expires'             => '0'
        ,   'Pragma'              => 'public'
    ];

    $list = $this->users->getAllUsers()->toArray();

    # add headers for each column in the CSV download
    array_unshift($list, array_keys($list[0]));

   $callback = function() use ($list) 
    {
        $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        foreach ($list as $row) { 
            fputcsv($FH, $row);
        }
        fclose($FH);
    };

    // return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers); // Old version
    return response()->download($callback, 'Users-' . date('d-m-Y'), $headers);

}
```

I've tried to use the Laravel 5.2 `response()` function, however I'm just getting a bit lost as to what I'm responding with – `download()` seems the logical option, but that gives me the following error:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Which makes sense. What is the right way of going about this? Or should I save the file and then just use the filepath as the first argument of my `download()` function – something that seems to be bad practise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was simple enough and worked great once I replaced the class & static call `Response::` With the helper function, `response()->`:

```
return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

I believe this uses the `StreamedResponse` class.